# ACR: How to get rid of the "ugh" sounds when jumping?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In *Assassin's Creed: Revelations* the developers apparently added new sounds when jumping/climbing which sound like "ugh" and they are **extremely annoying**.

Is there a way to get rid of these sounds? Hacking files is fine for me, I always play in offline mode so I don't have to care if the Ubisoft launcher dislikes modifications or not.

My guess is that all sounds are in `sounds_eng.pck` or `sounds_ger.pck`, but at least a quick google search didn't result in any tools to edit them.

Comment: Chances are its just a zip file. But it might also have some kind of security hash attached to it. Try to open with WinZip, exchange the file and save it again. Make a backup.

Comment: It's no standard file format; neither winrar nor total commander are able to "open" it and *GNU file* also doesn't have any information on the format.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - You are out of luck then.

Comment: Come on, the guy's getting old (Ezio). Be cool..

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make him stop that, but here are some options:

1. turn down the speech volume when you're roaming around.
2. play the game in a different language.
3. turn off the game volume.

Comment: You can turn subtitles on if you choose 3.